# rss not well-formed (invalid token) - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rss

```
XML parsing error: <unknown>:16:32: not well-formed (invalid token) [help]

<itunes:category text="Society & Culture">
```

I don't know how I can fix this error. you see I store all our shows in mongodb and the categories are set out by Apple the category we need to be in is Society & Culture - since they seem to not just have an entertainment category.

I am wondering how can I get this line of code to not stuff up when the & simple is shown.

```
'\n<itunes:category text="'+show.category+'">';
```

full code

```
router.get('/shows/:id', (req, res) => {
    var url = req.params.id;


    /*var obj = {
        items: [{
            name: url,
            _id: 1
        }, {
            name: 'two',
            _id: 2
        }, {
            name: 'three',
            _id: 3
        }],
        blah: 'http://www.google.com',
        when: new Date(),
        boolz: true,
        nullz: null
    };

    console.log(serializer.render(obj));*/

    var ep ='';
    var query = {};
    var epi='';
    query['url']=url;
    console.log(url);
    ShowModel.findOne(query).exec(function(err, show) {
        if (!err){ 

            var q = {}
            q['show_id']=show._id;
            EpisodeModel.find(q).sort('-pubDate').exec(function(er, a) {
                if (!er){ 
                   // console.log(a);
                    /*{a.map(a => (
                        ep += '\n<item>'+
                             '\n<title>'+a.title+'</title>'+
                             '\n<itunes:summary>'+a.summary+'</itunes:summary>'+
                             '\n<description>'+a.description+'</description>'+
                             '\n<link>'+a.link+'</link>'+
                             '\n<enclosure url="'+a.enclosureurl+'" type="audio/mpeg"></enclosure>'+
                             '\n<pubDate>Thu, 21 Dec 2016 16:01:07 +0000</pubDate>'+
                             '\n<itunes:author>Author Name</itunes:author>'+
                             '\n<itunes:duration>00:32:16</itunes:duration>'+
                             '\n<itunes:explicit>no</itunes:explicit>'+
                             '\n<guid>http://example.com/podcast-1</guid>'+
                             '\n</item>'                        
                      ))}*/
                      for(var k in a) {

                       // console.log(a[k].title);
                        ep+= '\n<item>'+
                             '\n<title>'+a[k].title+'</title>'+
                             '\n<itunes:summary>'+a[k].summary+'</itunes:summary>'+
                             '\n<description>'+a[k].description+'</description>'+
                             '\n<link>'+a[k].link+'</link>'+
                             '\n<enclosure url="https://dts.podtrac.com/redirect.mp3/'+a[k].enclosureurl+'" length="'+a[k].enclosurebyts+'" type="audio/mpeg"></enclosure>'+
                             '\n<pubDate>'+sdate(a[k].pubDate)+'</pubDate>'+
                             '\n<itunes:author>'+a[k].author+'</itunes:author>'+
                             '\n<itunes:episodeType>full</itunes:episodeType>'+
                             '\n<itunes:season>'+a[k].season+'</itunes:season>';
                             if(a[k].episode_no) ep+='\n<itunes:episode>'+a[k].episode_no+'</itunes:episode>';
                         ep+='\n<itunes:duration>'+a[k].duration+'</itunes:duration>'+
                             '\n<itunes:explicit>'+a[k].explicit+'</itunes:explicit>'+
                             '\n<guid>'+a[k].link+'</guid>'+
                             '\n</item>'
                        }

                }else{throw er;}
             // console.log(ep);





            if(show.subcategory){var subcategory = '<itunes:category text="'+show.subcategory+'"/>';}
            var feed = '<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:itunes="http://www.itunes.com/dtds/podcast-1.0.dtd" xmlns:creativeCommons="http://backend.userland.com/creativeCommonsRssModule" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/" version="2.0">'+
            '\n<channel>'+
                '\n<title>'+show.title+'</title>'+
                '\n<link>'+show.link+'</link>'+
                '\n<language>en-us</language>'+
                '\n<itunes:subtitle>'+show.subtitle+'</itunes:subtitle>'+
                '\n<itunes:author>Radio Media PTY LTD</itunes:author>'+
                '\n<itunes:summary>'+show.summary+'</itunes:summary>'+
                '\n<description>'+show.description+'</description>'+
                '\n<itunes:owner>'+
                    '\n<itunes:name>Radio Media PTY LTD</itunes:name>'+
                    '\n<itunes:email>podcast@radiomedia.com.au</itunes:email>'+
                '\n</itunes:owner>'+
                '\n<itunes:explicit>'+show.explicit+'</itunes:explicit>'+
                '\n<itunes:image href="'+show.icon+'" />'+
                '\n<itunes:category text="'+show.category+'">';
                    if(subcategory) feed += subcategory; 
                feed +='\n</itunes:category>'+
                '\n<atom:link href="http://api.radiomedia.com.au/api-access/shows/'+url+'" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />';

            feed += ep;    

            feed += '\n</channel>'+
            '\n</rss>';   
            console.log(ep); 

            res.header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');
            res.send(feed);
            //process.exit();
        }); } else { throw err; }

    });
```

Comment: How it's related to react?

Comment: @DennisVash the script is react/nodejs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [XML Definition](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#charsets):

> The ampersand character (&) and the left angle bracket (<) MUST NOT appear in their literal form, except when used as markup delimiters, or within a comment, a processing instruction, or a CDATA section. If they are needed elsewhere, they MUST be escaped.